# How to check if my baker is active?

Tags: baking, rpc

As I understand, if my baker doesn't have activity for a few days (how many?), it becomes inactive, and I will have to wait for a few cycles again to be assigned rewards.

My question is: how can I check programmatically if it's active or not using Tezos RPC? Or other method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Delegates will be tagged as “deactivated” after 5 cycles of inactivity and they will lose their baking rights"  ---cycles are approximately 3 days each, so about 15 days later you will lose baking rights.

source: https://tezos.gitlab.io/tezos/introduction/alphanet.html

Personally, rather than re-inventing the wheel, just use Kiln
"Kiln has the ability to notify you via Telegram if your Baker is in danger of being marked inactive. " So download the Kiln app from:
https://gitlab.com/obsidian.systems/kiln/-/releases

source: https://medium.com/@obsidian.systems/kiln-v0-3-0-introducing-baker-and-tezos-release-monitoring-b703f3f4d5c4

Comment: But when a delegated is tagged as "deactivated" what that means? Where is it tagged? Or it's just considered deactivated for reward calculation purposes, but no modification is done anywhere?

Comment: For example, if you are offline or have below 8000 Tezos in the account, you will be de-activated and not receive any endorsing or baking opportunities.   You can see if you are registered to bake by issuing the ./tezos-client setup ledger to bake for ALIAS --main-hwm CURRENTBLOCKNUMBER.  If you are already registered it will tell you, otherwise it will register you.

Comment: I don't think this answer actually answers the question. The question was how to check programmatically if my baker is active/unactive