# How to check baker status via RPC?

Tags: baker

I'm new to tezos and started my baker node on ubuntu via cli.

here is the status on explorer https://edo2net.tzkt.io/tz1e7r6xbFGoghLmv3z1a4DQV3JtYXHYufna/operations/
How can I check if my baker is activate or not via RPC?

Is there anything do I have to do to activate my baker like freezing balance/vote to my baker account?

I followed this https://github.com/serokell/tezos-packaging/blob/master/docs/baking.md#baking-with-tezos-packaging-on-ubuntu-and-raspberry-pi-os guide to setup on ubuntu.

I know you guys will feel like it's repetive question but I didn't get the answer for RPC here [How to check if my baker is active?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1838/how-to-check-if-my-baker-is-active)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following RPC to check the status:

https://edonet.smartpy.io/chains/main/blocks/head/context/delegates/tz1e7r6xbFGoghLmv3z1a4DQV3JtYXHYufna

```
{
  "balance":"22271433017",
  "frozen_balance":"0",
  "frozen_balance_by_cycle":[],
  "staking_balance":"22271433017",
  "delegated_contracts":[
    "tz1e7r6xbFGoghLmv3z1a4DQV3JtYXHYufna"
  ],
  "delegated_balance":"0",
  "deactivated":false,
  "grace_period":108,
  "voting_power":2
}
```

Your software seems to be down, you are not including nonce reveals.

To check the baking rights you can use https://tezos.gitlab.io/008/rpc.html#get-block-id-helpers-baking-rights

Comment: My baking node is up and showing me logs like `- 008-PtEdo2Zk.baking.forge: No slot found at level 21108` and tezos node having ```validator.chain: Update current head to Block Hash BKypvfimVyMaeXDXYPXqXpqR2D77ijyNMdXvbXGKuXJ5n3qJaea (level 211082, timestamp 2021-04-28T09:04:05-00:00, fitness 01::0000000000033889), same branch``` this. how to check if my machine/node is down?

Comment: I think everything's ok with the software. The baker doesn't include `seed_nonce_revelation`s just because he hasn't baked any block yet. So, it's normal. If you open the "Schedule" tab in the explorer you will see that there are no any baking or endorsing rights yet, so all you need is to wait until you receive any.

Comment: I just activated my baker account yesterday. Do you know how much time it'll take to activate the baker?

Comment: You will be actually activated in 2 cycles after registering as a baker, when your staking balance gets to the snapshot. Then you will participate in baking and endorsing rights distribution.

Comment: Ah got that in mainnet 1 cycle is approx 3 days. is that same for testnet as well?

Comment: In Edonet, cycles are 1/4 of the time. half the blocks and the half time per block.

Comment: My baker registration got included in block 208826 at cycle 101 and now it's 103 cycle. Hope it'll be activated in the next cycle.

Comment: Activated yes, but you won't get any rights for an additional 3 cycles in testnets. on mainnet, 1 cycle is  2.8444 days. (4096/60/24)